# How to overload connect in UserSocket module?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I tried to overload the `connect` method at `UserSocket` module by using different map in the signature, however, it didn't work, and the server will not connect no mater the used map is.. here is what I tried to do:

```
def connect(%{"token" => sent_token }, socket), do: connect(%{"token" => sent_token, "owner_id" => 1 }, socket)
def connect %{"token" => sent_token, "owner_id" => pased_owner_id }, socket do
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elixir executes the first function definition which matches the pattern, and a Map with keys other than the ones specified in a pattern are ignored. If you put the clause with `"owner_id"` before the other one, you should get the behavior you want:

```
def connect(%{"token" => sent_token, "owner_id" => pased_owner_id}, socket) do
def connect(%{"token" => sent_token}, socket), do: connect(%{"token" => sent_token, "owner_id" => 1 }, socket)
```

Demo:

```
iex(1)> data = %{"token" => 1, "owner_id" => 2}
%{"owner_id" => 2, "token" => 1}
iex(2)> match?(%{"token" => sent_token}, data)
true
iex(3)> match?(%{"token" => sent_token, "owner_id" => pased_owner_id}, data)
true
```

Comment: so, as I understand, the clause with `"owner_id"` will be always matched, therefor I don't need to have the second clause (without  `"owner_id"`) as it will never be matched.. right?

Comment: The clause with `"owner_id"` will be matched only if `"owner_id"` is present. From your code it looks like you're trying to set the `"owner_id"` to `1` if it's not present. In that case, you should have both the clauses, but just switch the order. Right now, your code is probably hanging as it's calling the same function clause again and again with the same arguments.

Comment: hmm, yea, it hangs as you said, thanks for explanation!

Comment: but why clause with `"owner_id"` will be matched only if "owner_id" is present? as Elixir executes the first function definition which matches the pattern, thus, if the clause with `"owner_id"` is the first one, then it will be always matched, even if `"owner_id"` is not present, as the demo you put in the answer.. ??

Comment: now I understand, the Map will match with minimal keys, extra keys are just ignored.. thanks

Comment: Yes, Elixir will match the first pattern with matching key/values _but_ also ignore any extra key/values in the actual argument. If you match with `%{}`, it will match _any_ Map (empty or with 1 entry or with 10 entries or any number of entries).